# N00b Question: ValueError: Attempted Relative import in non-package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I hope you guys can help.

I'm writing a small code to make yeelights flash random colors when a button is pressed. I'm importing something for a project and I'm getting a value error in my code.

From my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import random
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library
from yeelight import Bulb
from yeelight import *
from .utils import _clamp

ChangeTableLight = Bulb("192.xxx.xx.xx") #Change Table Lightbulb
brightness = 100
count = _clamp(count, 1, 9)
#HSVTransition(hue, saturation, duration, brightness)

transitions = [
    HSVTransition(random.randint(0, 360), 100, duration=duration, brightness=brightness) for _ in range(count)
]

flow = Flow(
    count=5,
    action=Flow.actions.recover,
    transitions=transitions
)

def button_callback(channel):
    ChangeTableLight.start_flow(flow)
```

then I have in my code (where the error is appearing - Line 8)

`count = _clamp(count, 1, 9)`

When I run the script and get this error:

**from .utils import _clamp ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package**

I've tried searching to see if I have to download a specific utilities module to import, I've tried importing different modules, etc, but I can't find anything.

On another forum someone recommended I remove the period before utils in the import but that gave me this error:

**From utility import _clamp ImportError: cannot import name _clamp**

The Yeelight python code comes from [here](https://yeelight.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Any suggestions to help guide me to the right answer?

Comment: One import variant imports from `utils`, the other from `utility`?

Comment: Does `from util import` work?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'm not quite sure what you're asking,

Comment: @Justlearnedit Unfortunately not ;-(

Comment: The two error messages refer to imports from different modules/packages: `from .utils` and `From utility` (where the `from` must also be lowercase).

Comment: @MichaelButscher from utils.

Answer (score 0):

This is more right (1 error instead of 2) because you do absolute imports with installed modules.

```
from utility import _clamp
```

This is a relative import.

```
from .utils import _clamp
```

_clamp is a protected variable because it has a leading underscore access modifier. It's not supposed to be imported. We don't know if "_clamp" is from "utility" or "utils".

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I tried your suggestion and I get the error:

ImportError: No module named utility

I sudo pip install'd utility and still got that error.